# Behind the scenes of construction of a thread

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stdthread

It is known that how to use thread. But how is the thread library implemented. I mean, like we have `std::string`, its functionality can be somewhat replicated, by user himself using **C-strings (char arrays)**, it is easy.

My question is how can i achieve this for the case of thread, like how can i create a class with bare-minimum C++ datatypes and functions(without WINAPI), std::thread like functionality into a class.

I would like to give a example, my teacher has prohibited me from using std::string, and allowed to only use C-strings, but i can use **OOP** concepts..

```
class string_my
{  
      private:
            char* str;
      public:
         // all the required func. to store the value in char*
 }
```

Comment: So what do you want? Create your own string class or create a thread class without the use of any operating system API? In case you want to do the latter: it's entirely impossible. Thread management belongs into the realm of the operating system's scheduler.

Comment: @Jodocus i want to create a thread class....was trying to exemplify it using string class

Comment: On Linux, the [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) system call with a `CLONE_THREAD` argument is what ultimately creates a thread.

Comment: This is the right thinking. When the instructor says, don't use `std::string` and `std::string` is the correct solution, write your own string class. Same with `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot implement a thread class without either using the OS provided threading primitives or some higher level threading library (like `boost::thread` or `std::thread`) that in turn rely on said OS-provided threading primitives.